# Fancyhdr and scrreprt

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr

I try to use `scrreprt` and `fancyhdr` for getting the chapter at the head of even pages left and the section at odd pages right:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twosides]{scrreprt}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark} 
 \fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark} 
 \fancyhead[LO]{}
 \fancyhead[RE]{}
 \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

But actually I want to use `scrreport` without the `twoside` argument, so that the pages are all the same (margins left etc.). When I use

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark} 
 \fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark} 
 \fancyhead[LO]{}
 \fancyhead[RE]{}
 \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

I just get chapter and section at the head of every page. Is there a way to define odd and even pages without the `twoside` argument by setting `scrreprt`? Or exists a simple package for doing this?

Comment: Do *not* use »[fancyhdr](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)« with classes from »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)«. Migrate to the »scrlayer-scrpage« package (or »scrpage2« in older versions). They are described in the »[KOMA-Script](http://texdoc.net/pkg/koma-script)« user guide.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: `fancyhdr` could also be used with KOMA-Script classes, as clearly is written in KOMA-Script documentation. But of course it is much better to use the dedicated KOMA-Script package(s).

Comment: @Speravir: But it is not recommended because it does not support the diverse interfaces that »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)« offers to modify certain elements. And I didn't say with any word that it can't be used.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: I understood your first sentence in comment this way …

Comment: @Speravir: Then you obviously misunderstood that sentence. There is a significant difference in "don't use" and "you can't use".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `twoside=semi` option so you have equal margins.

Then, to achieve what you want, we use the `scrlayer-scrpage` package instead of `fancyhdr` which is not recommended for KOMA classes.

We load `scrlayer-scrpage` in this way

```
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

The `automark` option is to automatically create running headers, while `headsepline` is to print the header line in non-plain pages.

At this point we clear headers and footers for all pages with the command

```
\clearpairofpagestyles
```

and then, with the following lines,

```
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\lehead{\headmark}
\rohead{\headmark}
```

we set the page number at the center of the footer in all pages and the running headers in non-plain ones.

And, finally, we say that we want to use the newly created style with the command

```
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside=semi]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\lehead{\headmark}
\rohead{\headmark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum[1-5]

\section{A section}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thats nice so far, thank you for that! But there are two more points, which makes it complete: 1. A horizontal line between the header and text would be nice, like in the fancyhdr package. 2. I got a two sides introduction and at the second page I then get a header too. How could one avoid the header at one page?

Comment: @dalvo I've completely rewritten the answer to achieve what you want.

Comment: Instead of `scrpage2`, shouldn't you use `scrlayer-scrpage`?

Comment: @dalvo To avoid the headers for one page, issue a `\thispagestyle{scrplain}`

Comment: I know, but it should be the way to go. Technically `scrpage2` is deprecated (according to the KOMA-Script documentation).

Comment: It seems that my Koma-Package is too old (so scrlayer package doesn't exists). I will update it tomorrow, but it locks good for me.

Comment: @Manuel: No, it is not _yet_ considered as deprecated. But everything, what works on user level with `scrpage2`, does also work with `scrlayer-scrpage`, and the latter does provide more features. Sometime in one of the next vesions `scrpage2` _will_ be declared as deprecated, though.

Comment: @karlkoeller I tried it today and it works perfect. Thank you! Maybe the headers size can be a a little smaller, that it is a bit smaller than the text. But your answers is still very good, thanks again.

Comment: @dalvo Add the line `\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont\normalcolor\slshape\small}` in the preamble to achieve this.

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks, now it looks perfect to me. :)

Comment: @dalvo Happy about that:-)