# Header not working

Tags: header-footer, footer

The following tex code should produce a header with the code I found here: [Fancyhdr and scrreprt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161439/fancyhdr-and-scrreprt?newreg=4e829bef56524f89aa818535b02fc1df)

My Code:

```
\documentclass[%
pdftex,
a4paper,
12pt,
parskip,
bibliography=totoc,
listof=totoc
]{scrreprt}

% Kopf und Fusszeile
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\lehead{\headmark}
\rohead{\headmark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

%Dokument beginnt
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

Text Text Text TextText Text Text TextText Text Text TextText Text Text TextText Text Text Text

\section{A section}

Text Text Text TextText Text Text TextText Text Text TextText Text Text TextText Text Text Text

\end{document}
```

But it outputs no Header or Footer.

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards

Comment: Chapter pages uses page style `plain` by default. The optional argument of `\cfoot` etc. sets the content of the element for the `plain` style. So there is a page number in footer of the chapter page. If you really need the header entry in `plain` style use `\ohead*{\headmark}` which is a short version of `\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}`. You can also change the page style of the chapter pages to `scrheadings`:  `\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}`.

Comment: `scrreprt` produces a onesided document by default. In onesided documents there are no left hand sided (even) pages. Therefore `\lehead` is useless in the MWE.